# JBOSS ESB(Jboss developer studio)

Tags: jboss, jboss-esb, jboss-eap-6

In **JBOSS Developer Studio** while creating **ESB Project** I am getting following error

```
 java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jboss/tools/esb/core/runtime/JBossRuntimeManager
    at    org.jboss.tools.esb.project.ui.preference.controls.JBossESBRuntimePreferencePage.<init>(JBossESBRuntimePreferencePage.java:43)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:525)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:372)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:325)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.osgi.RegistryStrategyOSGI.createExecutableExtension(RegistryStrategyOSGI.java:184)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ExtensionRegistry.createExecutableExtension(ExtensionRegistry.java:905)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ConfigurationElement.createExecutableExtension(ConfigurationElement.java:243)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ConfigurationElementHandle.createExecutableExtension(ConfigurationElementHandle.java:55)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPlugin.createExtension(WorkbenchPlugin.java:274)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.dialogs.WorkbenchPreferenceNode.createPage(WorkbenchPreferenceNode.java:47)
    at org.eclipse.jface.preference.PreferenceDialog.createPage(PreferenceDialog.java:1340)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.dialogs.FilteredPreferenceDialog.createPage(FilteredPreferenceDialog.java:377)
    at org.eclipse.jface.preference.PreferenceDialog.showPage(PreferenceDialog.java:1231)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.dialogs.FilteredPreferenceDialog.showPage(FilteredPreferenceDialog.java:675)
    at org.eclipse.jface.preference.PreferenceDialog$10.run(PreferenceDialog.java:709)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(BusyIndicator.java:70)
    at org.eclipse.jface.preference.PreferenceDialog$9.selectionChanged(PreferenceDialog.java:705)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer$3.run(StructuredViewer.java:888)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.JFaceUtil$1.run(JFaceUtil.java:49)
    at org.eclipse.jface.util.SafeRunnable.run(SafeRunnable.java:175)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.firePostSelectionChanged(StructuredViewer.java:886)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.handlePostSelect(StructuredViewer.java:1226)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer$5.widgetSelected(StructuredViewer.java:1251)
    at org.eclipse.jface.util.OpenStrategy.firePostSelectionEvent(OpenStrategy.java:262)
    at org.eclipse.jface.util.OpenStrategy.access$5(OpenStrategy.java:256)
    at org.eclipse.jface.util.OpenStrategy$3.run(OpenStrategy.java:433)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.RunnableLock.run(RunnableLock.java:35)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.runAsyncMessages(Synchronizer.java:135)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runAsyncMessages(Display.java:4145)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3762)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.runEventLoop(Window.java:826)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.open(Window.java:802)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.dialogs.WorkbenchPreferenceDialog.open(WorkbenchPreferenceDialog.java:215)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.OpenPreferencesAction.run(OpenPreferencesAction.java:65)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.Action.runWithEvent(Action.java:499)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.handleWidgetSelection(ActionContributionItem.java:584)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.access$2(ActionContributionItem.java:501)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem$5.handleEvent(ActionContributionItem.java:411)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1057)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4170)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3759)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$9.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1113)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:997)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:138)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:610)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:567)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:150)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:124)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:354)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:181)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:636)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:591)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1450)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1426)
Caused by: org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseLazyStarter$TerminatingClassNotFoundException: An error occurred while automatically activating bundle org.jboss.tools.esb.project.core (937).
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseLazyStarter.postFindLocalClass(EclipseLazyStarter.java:124)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.findLocalClass(ClasspathManager.java:469)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.findLocalClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:216)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findLocalClass(BundleLoader.java:395)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:464)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:421)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:412)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:107)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.loadClass(BundleLoader.java:340)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.loadClass(BundleHost.java:229)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.loadClass(AbstractBundle.java:1212)
    at org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.core.util.internal.Versionable.getVersionComparator(Versionable.java:153)
    at org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.core.internal.FacetedProjectFrameworkImpl.calculateVersionComparisonTables(FacetedProjectFrameworkImpl.java:1658)
    at org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.core.internal.FacetedProjectFrameworkImpl.readMetadata(FacetedProjectFrameworkImpl.java:1386)
    at org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.core.internal.FacetedProjectFrameworkImpl.<init>(FacetedProjectFrameworkImpl.java:188)
    at org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.core.internal.FacetedProjectFrameworkImpl.getInstance(FacetedProjectFrameworkImpl.java:211)
    at org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.core.FacetedProjectFramework.initialize(FacetedProjectFramework.java:281)
    at org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.core.FacetedProjectFramework.addListener(FacetedProjectFramework.java:223)
    at org.jboss.ide.eclipse.as.core.JBossServerCorePlugin$1.run(JBossServerCorePlugin.java:78)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:53)
Caused by: org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Exception in org.jboss.tools.esb.core.ESBProjectCorePlugin.start() of bundle org.jboss.tools.esb.project.core.
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:734)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.startWorker(BundleHost.java:381)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.start(AbstractBundle.java:300)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.util.SecureAction.start(SecureAction.java:478)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.setLazyTrigger(BundleLoader.java:263)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseLazyStarter.postFindLocalClass(EclipseLazyStarter.java:109)
    ... 20 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.jboss.ide.eclipse.as.core.publishers.PublishUtil.addModuleCoreFactory(Ljava/lang/String;)V
    at org.jboss.tools.esb.core.ESBProjectCorePlugin.start(ESBProjectCorePlugin.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl$1.run(BundleContextImpl.java:711)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:702)
    ... 26 more
```

Comment: JBoss Developer Studio :Version: 7.0.0.GA,  jbossesb-server-4.12  ,

Comment: I had solved my problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
jbosstools-integration-stack-aggregate-4.1.1-SNAPSHOT needs to plugin for jboss developer    studio.So,we can set ESB environment.And create JBOSS ESB project properly with out an error.
```